# matplotlib contour of sparse (regular) data shows artefacts

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I would like to contour data that are quite sparse and where a maximum is going diagonally through the picture; the matplotlib contour function invents minima between the sampled maxima.

Starting with the densely sampled case where everything looks as expected:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

x_1D = np.linspace(0., 10., 100)
y_1D = np.linspace(0., 10., 100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x_1D, y_1D)
z = np.empty_like(x)
def peak(y, y0):
    return np.exp(-(y-y0)**2)
for i in range(x_1D.size):
    z[:,i] = peak(y_1D, i/x_1D.size*y_1D.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

ax[0].set_title('measured data')
ax[0].scatter(x, y, marker='s', c=z, cmap=plt.cm.jet, s=25)

ax[1].set_title('contour')
ax[1].contourf(x, y, z, levels=14, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

# define grid
xi = np.linspace(x_1D.min()-0.1, x_1D.max()+0.1, 1000)
yi = np.linspace(y_1D.min()-0.1, y_1D.max()+0.1, 1000)

# grid the data
triang = tri.Triangulation(x.flatten(), y.flatten())
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z.flatten())
Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = interpolator(Xi, Yi)

ax[2].set_title('interpolated')
ax[2].contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=14, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

When x is sampled less by a factor 10, i.e. `x_1D = np.linspace(0., 10., 10)`, minima appear between the sampled maxima in the contour plot.

[image]

Is there a way how to avoid this artefact and make the contour of the sparsely sampled data look like the one of the densely sampled data?

EDIT: Thanks for the answer that works very nicely on the example I provided. Unfortunately, I have simplified the problem too far. Rather than talking about one diagonal line, I should have enquired about an arbitrary number of peaks moving in arbitrary directions through the picture; e.g. replace the peak-generation by

```
z = np.zeros_like(x)
def peak(y, y0):
    return np.exp(-(y-y0)**2)
for i in range(x_1D.size):
    z[:,i] += peak(y_1D, np.cos(i/x_1D.size*np.pi)*y_1D.max()*0.05+y_1D.max()*0.8)
for i in range(x_1D.size):
    z[:,i] += peak(y_1D, np.sin(i/x_1D.size*np.pi/2.)*y_1D.max()*0.5)
```

resulting in
[image]

Comment: There are lots of different ways to interpolate data.  In general if you want to preserve a spatial structure on some scale you need to sample it twice, and you aren’t doing that, hence artifacts.  But if you know there is a preferred correlation in certain directions you can specify that preferred direction in the interpolation routine.  I’d suggest looking at scipy and their twos interpolation routines

Comment: Thanks! Could you please expand on how to sample it twice? I played a bit with scipy.interpolate but didn't find a 'preferred direction' setting. Also I guess that won't work if there were several peaks moving through the image, right?

Comment: There isn't any magic way to fix this - you have a signal that is changing too rapidly for your sample rate.  You can smooth `z` is x enough to damp out the high frequencies your sampling is inducing.  i.e. `z[j, :] = np.convolve(z[j, :], np.ones(3)/3, 'same')` at the obvious expense of sharpness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your approach is that the triangulation algorithm doesn't know that the peaks should be connecting to eachother between the "x-slices" (your line of dense data points for a constant x).

Simplifying a bit, the triangulation algorithm will look at the neighbours in the x and y direction and connect to those. Then, when trying to interpolate using this triangulation, the points between the peaks will be roughly an average of the nearest points in the x direction and hence the minima will appear. The best solution is to make your own triangulation, with the peaks connected directly.

Fortunately, we can actually hack the triangulation to make it connect to the peaks by shifting the coordinates in the y direction such that the peaks are all aligned horizontally. This works because the triangulation algorithm uses the coordinates that you pass it. In your example this is easy to accomplish because we can just apply the simple shift `y_s = y - x`. In general you would have to get the equation for your peak (call it `y_p(x)`) and then subtract that from `y` to get the `y_s`.

Now that you have a shifted triangulation, you can make a new denser grid (like you did) and apply the same shift. Then, you interpolate in the shifted mesh with the shifted dense grid to get the z values correctly interpolated. Finally, you un-shift the dense grid to get the correct y values and plot it.

Below is the code of applying this concept to your code and the final result. As you can see. It works quite well for this case.

[image: Results With Shift]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

def peak(y, y0):
    return np.exp(-(y-y0)**2)

x_1D = np.linspace(0., 10., 10)
y_1D = np.linspace(0., 10., 100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x_1D, y_1D)
z = np.empty_like(x)

for i in range(x_1D.size):
    z[:,i] = peak(y_1D, i/x_1D.size*y_1D.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4)

ax[0].set_title('measured data')
ax[0].scatter(x, y, marker='s', c=z, cmap=plt.cm.jet, s=25)

ax[1].set_title('contour')
ax[1].contourf(x, y, z, levels=14, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

# define output grid
xi_1D = np.linspace(x_1D.min()-0.1, x_1D.max()+0.1, 1000)
yi_1D = np.linspace(y_1D.min()-0.1, y_1D.max()+0.1, 1000)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi_1D, yi_1D)

# Old Linear Interpolation
triang = tri.Triangulation(x.flatten(), y.flatten())
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z.flatten())
zi = interpolator(xi, yi)

ax[2].set_title('interpolated')
ax[2].contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=14, cmap=plt.cm.jet)

# === SHIFTED LINEAR INTERPOLATION ===

# make shifted interpolating mesh for the data
y_s=y-x
triang_s = tri.Triangulation(x.flatten(), y_s.flatten())
interpolator_s = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang_s, z.flatten())

# interpolate in the shifted state
yi_s = yi-xi
zi_s = interpolator_s(xi, yi_s)

# unshift the fine mesh
yi_us = yi_s+xi

ax[3].set_title('interpolated (shifted)')
ax[3].contourf(xi, yi_us, zi_s, levels=14, cmap=plt.cm.jet)


plt.show()
```